# Error creating virtual directory, IIS in visual studio 2010 and in windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

When I try to create virtual directory, following dialogue box appears:

[Error while creating virtual directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j55k9.png)

I tried aspnet_regiis -i but it prompt like this:

[command prompt error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh2B9.png)

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Server Manager and Use Roles and Features to install .Net Features in a Windows Server OS.

You can also use dism to enable the feature using command line.

For Desktop OS you can use appwiz.cpl and select Turn on feature on off

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I already have these as you suggested and still not working.